# Pattern matching on list of lists

Tags: haskell

I want to make a first character of a string  if it's not. This is what I'm doing:

```
import Data.Char

onlyCapitals :: [String] -> [String]
onlyCapitals [] = []
onlyCapitals (x:xs) = if isUpper $ head x 
                      then x ++ onlyCapitals xs  -- 1
                      else toUpper (head x) : tail x ++ onlyCapitals xs -- 2 and 3

main = print $ onlyCapitals ["Aaaa", "bbb", "ffff"]
```

And I got 3 errors:

```
Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
    Expected type: [String]
      Actual type: String

Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: Char

Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
    Expected type: [String]
      Actual type: String
```

Comment: It pays off to write easy code. For example, a function `cap` that capitalizes a String. Then your `onlyCapitals`becomes simply `map cap`

Comment: Should your first sentence read: "I want to make the first character of a string a capital if it's not one already"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to realize

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
(:)  :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

So your first error is that you try to do something like `String ++ [String]` which is a type error, instead you want `(:)`

The next problem is

```
toUpper (head x) : tail x ++ onlyCapitals xs
```

The problem is the associativity and precedence of `++` and `:` are both the same level to the right. So this is parsed as

```
toUpper (head x) : (tail x ++ onlyCapitals xs)
```

this is fixed with explicit parens and switching `++` to `:` again

```
(toUpper (head x) : tail x) : onlyCapitals xs
```

#### Style notes

Now this works, except if you pass it an empty string in which case it'll crash. Instead maybe something like this would be nicer

```
onlyCapitals :: [String] -> [String]
onlyCapitals = map cap
  where cap "" = ""
        cap (x : xs) = toUpper x : xs
```

We abstract away the explicit recursion and construction of the list and just leave it to `map`. Then we properly handle `""` and capitalize the first character of nonempty strings.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the line you marked `-- 1`: `then x ++ onlyCapitals xs`. The type of `x` is `String`, while the type of `onlyCapitals xs` is `[String]`. The `++` operator requires its two operands to be of the same type and it assumes them to be lists. The left operand is a `[Char]` and it then expect the right operand to be `[Char]` as well. As the right operand is in fact `[String]`, which is `[[Char]]`, it thus reports: "couldn't match type `[Char]` with `[[Char]]`", simplified to "couldn't match type `Char` with `[Char]`", as the 'outer' list could be matched.

So you don't want to use the `++` operator there, but rather the `:` operator. The other errors stem from a similar problem on the line marked `-- 2 and 3` and the solution is to very carefully check what types your subexpressions have and in what order the operators are applied.

One note on this method: you don't actually need the conditional. toUpper on something that is already a capital works just fine, so the 'else' can just be applied to every member of the list.